# Is it possible that a security with a positive variance can have a required return that is less than the risk free rate?

Tags: implied-volatility

I'm not sure of the answer but I think it's possible. What I don't get is what characteristics this asset would need to have and why it would mean that an investor would accept a return less than the risk free rate when there is uncertainty about the asset's future payoffs.

Answer (score 2):

If the security has negative correlation with other assets that enjoy attractive risk-free rates, then it can be attractive at a return rate under the risk-free level.

It would, of course, never be attractive in a single-security portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, such an asset would not exists with standard deviation less than the risk free rate. You have rightly pointed out that if risk free rate is higher than any rational investor would not invest in the instrument, given lower return along with some amount of risk, when the investor can earn more amount without any risk.

In the real world we do not appropriate measure of risk/conditional risk estimation, which may add to the confusion.